# Is there any way to align vertically aligned text in a table and a simple inline element?

Tags: html, css, layout

Is there any way to align vertically aligned text in a table and a simple inline element? without setting the explicit height or line-height?
https://jsfiddle.net/3xg92szL/

```
<style>
  body {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .inline-table {
    display: inline-table;
  }

  .aligned-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .va-middle {
    vertical-align: middle; 
  }

  .square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #FFDFD3; 
  }
</style>
<span class="inline-table square">
  <span class="aligned-cell">text in cell</span>
</span>
<span class="va-middle">vertical-align: middle;</span>
<span>vertical-align: baseline;</span>
```

Comment: you are not using table element in your example and yet you are asking a question about table. Change your code to use table

Comment: I'm using display: inline-table

Answer (score 0):

Since you prefer not to use table element, there are several ways to make an element behave like `<table>`

here is some recommendation page for you :
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp


you might want to trick your code using `<div>` element with `display: inline-block;` property to adjust it's heights.

Comment: How can I adjust the height of div that's inlined?

Comment: you can use `display: inline-block;`, I edited my answer.. hopely it helps :)

Comment: I haven't find any way to align the text vertically inside `display: inline-block;`
That is the reason I utilized `display: table-cell`;

Comment: put some more `div` inside it, or try `display: flex;`